# .NET Maui ListView binding works in Android but not Windows

Tags: data-binding, maui

Doing my first .NET MAUI app, and was attempting to scan for Bluetooth LE Devices and connect to one using [InTheHand.BluetoothLE](https://github.com/inthehand/32feet/tree/main/InTheHand.BluetoothLE). The library appears to be working great but have a strange issue with DataBinding. I am using a `ListView` bound to a Collection decorated with `[ObservableProperty]`. When built for Android, everything works well and the items are shown. When built for Windows however, the data gets populated and items are there, but the Text is blank and many binding failures are reported.

Android (Databinds appear to work fine):

[image: Databinds appear to work fine]

Windows (Items are present but Databinding failures):

[image: Items are present but Databinding failures]

The page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Bluetooth_PoC.ViewModel"
             x:Class="Bluetooth_PoC.MainPage"
             Loaded="MainPage_Loaded">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:MainPageViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,5"
            VerticalOptions="Start">

            <Button
                x:Name="BluetoothScanBtn"
                Text="Scan for Bluetooth LE Devices"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Scans for Bluetooth LE Devices"
                Command="{Binding StartDiscoveryCommand}"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <ListView x:Name="BluetoothDeviceListView"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding DiscoveredDevices}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}"
                                  Detail="{Binding Id}"
                                  Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainPageViewModel}}, Path=ConnectCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <Label
                Text="Connected Device"
                FontAttributes="Bold"/>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

The code behind:

```
using Bluetooth_PoC.ViewModel;

namespace Bluetooth_PoC;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage(MainPageViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = vm;
    }

    private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await CheckAndRequestBluetoothPermission();
    }

    private static async Task CheckAndRequestBluetoothPermission()
    {
        if (!await BluetoothHelper.CheckBluetoothStatus())
        {
            await BluetoothHelper.RequestBluetoothAccess();
        }
    }
}
```

The ViewModel:

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using InTheHand.Bluetooth;

namespace Bluetooth_PoC.ViewModel
{
    public partial class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
        }

        [ObservableProperty]
        public IReadOnlyCollection<BluetoothDevice> discoveredDevices;

        [RelayCommand]
        public async void StartDiscovery()
        {
            if (!await DiscoverDevices())
            {
                await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("No devices discovered!", "No Bluetooth devices were discovered.", "Cancel");
            }
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        public async void Connect(BluetoothDevice device)
        {
            await device.Gatt.ConnectAsync();

            if (device.Gatt.IsConnected)
            {
                var services = await device.Gatt.GetPrimaryServicesAsync();

                await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Got Services!", $"Wow, it worked {services}", "Close");
            }
        }
        
        private async Task<bool> DiscoverDevices()
        {
            DiscoveredDevices = null;
            DiscoveredDevices = await Bluetooth.ScanForDevicesAsync(new RequestDeviceOptions() { AcceptAllDevices = true });

            return DiscoveredDevices.Count > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

BluetoothHelper.cs

```
using Bluetooth_PoC;

public static class BluetoothHelper
{
    public static async Task<bool> CheckBluetoothStatus()
    {
        try
        {
            var requestStatus = await new BluetoothPermissions().CheckStatusAsync();
            return requestStatus == PermissionStatus.Granted;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // logger.LogError(ex);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static async Task<bool> RequestBluetoothAccess()
    {
        try
        {
            var requestStatus = await new BluetoothPermissions().RequestAsync();
            return requestStatus == PermissionStatus.Granted;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // logger.LogError(ex);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can change the listview to collectionview and try to build the project again.

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT items are still invisible with collectionview but now I cant even click on them

Comment: Did the visual studio provide some error information?

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT This time no binding errors. The area of the view does expand indicating that it was filled with the items, but each item is invisible if that makes sense. To be more clear, listview produced binding errors but I could still click on the times. Collectionview has no binding errors but now cannot click on the items

Comment: Can you provide the `BluetoothHelper` method? I can make a test on my side.

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT Added to main post at bottom per request

Comment: I tested the code with the static data on my side and it worked well. So this might not be the data binding problem. You can check does windows recognize the pairing.

Comment: @Hershizer33 I am actually seeing the same kind of error. Did you manage to solve this?